# "NULL not allowed" with two @OneToMany's to the same table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
@Entity
public class MarketSettlement extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FinancialTransaction> commissionPaid;

    @Setter @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FinancialTransaction> dividends;
}
```

So, a market settlement may generate dividends, and it may have commission paid.

However, it's valid for a settlement to generate dividends, and *NOT* pay any commission - in which case the `commissionPaid` collection is empty.

However, the table that is generated from this requires *BOTH* collections to be populated:

```
+------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| MarketSettlement_id          | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dividends_transactionId      | bigint(20) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| commissionPaid_transactionId | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Therefore, when i try to persist a record without any transactions, I get a `DataIntegrtityViolationException:`

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: NULL not
>   allowed for column "COMMISSIONPAID_TRANSACTIONID";

What's the correct way to configure this, to allow dividend transactions, but no commission transactions?

Comment: You can use a @JoinTable to have separate tables for your commission paid and the dividend component.

Comment: @dinukadev Thanks... that's what I ended up doing.  Mind posting this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Done. And good to know we both agreed on the same solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a @JoinTable to have separate tables for your commission paid and the dividend component.